# Check if the current time fall in range with different date in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

i want to check the time that falls into two different date.
assume that i need to check from 10:30pm from this day up to 7am of tomorrow.

```
TimeSpan NightShiftStart = new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0);//10:30pm 
TimeSpan NightShiftEnd = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0); //7am
```

and compare it

```
if ((now > NightShiftStart ) && (now < NightShiftEnd )){}
```

timespan wont work on this i also tried

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.Today.AddHours(22);
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(7);
```

still no luck.

Comment: Can you show your code for testing with `DateTime` as that should work.  Thought you forgot `AddMinutes(30)`.  Also if you are always working with todays dates then you really only want to know if the time is after 10:30 pm since it's never tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TimeOfDay property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx) and use that instead. So your code should look like this

```
if (now.TimeOfDay > NightShiftStart || now.TimeOfDay < NightShiftEnd ){}
```

**EDIT:** While the above code is fine for what you asked, this way is a bit more generic and works for all kinds of shifts, as long as you know when they start and end:

```
TimeSpan ShiftStart = new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0);//10:30pm 
TimeSpan ShiftEnd = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0); //7am

if ((ShiftStart > ShiftEnd && (now.TimeOfDay > ShiftStart || now.TimeOfDay < ShiftEnd))
   || (now.TimeOfDay > ShiftStart && now.TimeOfDay < ShiftEnd))
{
    // ...
}
```

Usually you should use >= or <= for comparing either ShiftStart or ShiftEnd as you want an exact time to also fall into one of your shifts.

Comment: You need `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: oh thanks didn't really think about it, but I guess you should also check if start is below end and treat it differently

Comment: That's not really comparing to tomorrow at 7am, just if it's before 7am regardless of the date.

Comment: thank you for the quick response and it was working well now. i didnt think about changing the AND to OR. but the problem its not taking the date.

Comment: @Denver I've made an edit to my code so it will work for all shifts/time checks not just the night shift

Comment: @Staeff sorry for a bit late of reply i did a couple of test of your code and YES it's now working just like the way i wanted. This is a big help and time consuming. thank you.

Comment: Time ranges are always half-open intervals.  (22:30 would be in range, but the shift is *over* at 07:00.)  Use inclusive comparison operators against `ShiftStart`, and exclusive operators against `ShiftEnd`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It is a simple but effective way:

```c#
private bool CheckIfTimeIsBetweenShift(DateTime time)
{
    var NightShiftStart = new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0); 
    var NightShiftEnd = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0);

    return NightShiftStart <= time.TimeOfDay && time.TimeOfDay >= NightShiftEnd;
}
```